Integrating a Scrapfly Scraper into an Azure Synapse Analytics Project
I am currently working on a project called “Azure-Social-Media-Analytics-Solution-Accelerator”. This project utilizes data from two main sources: news sites and Twitter. The data is collected and processed by Jupyter notebooks, which are run by Azure Synapse Analytics through a pipeline.
At present, the project uses the Twitter API to fetch data from Twitter. However, I wish to replace the Twitter API with a Scrapfly scraper that I have developed. My scraper uses the Scrapfly API to scrape data from Twitter and is defined in two Python files.
I have tried to update the Ingest Process file notebook in my project to use the Scrapfly scraper instead of the Twitter API. However, I am unsure of the best way to proceed.
Does anyone have experience with integrating a custom scraper into an Azure Synapse Analytics project? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!


Another option you can use is call the API in Azure Function App as  HTTP Trigger and http code then use it in your Synapse pipeline:-

Azure Functions Http Trigger:-
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from scrapfly import ScrapeConfig, ScrapflyClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    
    scrapfly = ScrapflyClient(key='scp-live-390c9xxxxxx54ce36')
    api_response = scrapfly.scrape(scrape_config=ScrapeConfig(url='https://httpbin.dev/anything'))
    logging.info(f'Scraping Result: {api_response.success}')
    scrape_result = api_response.scrape_result
    content = scrape_result['content']
    context = api_response.context
    status_code = api_response.status_code
    upstream_status_code = api_response.upstream_status_code

    return func.HttpResponse(
        f"Scrape Result: {api_response.success}. Content: {content}. Context: {context}. Status Code: {status_code}. Upstream Status Code: {upstream_status_code}",
        status_code=200
    )



You can also create a Logic App workflow to call the Scrapfly API like below then call the Logic App url into Azure synapse web activity:-

Scrapfly API:-
{
    "url": "https://api.scrapfly.io/scrape",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "url": "https://twitter.com",
        "key": "xxxxxxxxx5fc8fa67dso",
        "proxy_pool": "public_datacenter_pool",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "Cookie": "test=1;auth=1"
        },
        "country": "us",
        "lang": "en",
        "os": "win11",
        "timeout": 30000
    }
}


Then invoke this Logic app via Azure synapse Web activity similar to this MS document used to invoke email from logic app in web activity

Thank you for your comprehensive explanation of how to integrate the Twitter scraper into my Azure Social Media Analytics project. I'm particularly interested in exploring the approach using an Azure Function, as you suggested and would appreciate your guidance in implementing this solution. To help me get started, would you be willing to take a look at the project details? I've included the link to the project repository here: https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Social-Media-Analytics-Solution-Accelerator.

Refer this Azure Functions guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration to create http trigger function and try using my code from the asnwer
